# I am getting Type Error JSON is not serializable

Tags: python, json, datetime

Example of how the date come in the file: #"10/1/15 8:02"
I need to return the data in datetime as a datetime object. 
I tried to convert it, but it gives me the attributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'datetime'

```
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()
```

Code so far:

```
import csv
import json
from datetime import datetime
import string

file_name = ""
json_file = ""

reader = csv.reader(file_name)
reader.next()
for row in reader:
    person = row[0]
    datetime = datetime.strptime(row[1], '%m/%d/%y %I:%M')
    floor_level = row[2]
    building = row[3]

    final_dict = {'person_id':person,
                    'datetime': datetime,
                    'floor_level': int(floor_level),
                    'building': building
                    }

    json.dump(final_dict, json_file, indent=4,)
    json_file.write('\n')
```

Any ideas or resources?(note I removed the encoder from the json.dump)

Comment: You're already importing the inner datetime with `from datetime import datetime`.  Just use `if isinstance(o, datetime)`.

Comment: That worked. Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This import statement:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

is already getting the inner datetime type; you don't need to do it again by referencing `datetime.datetime`.  Just use this:

```
if isinstance(o, datetime):
```